# How to nested loop in react native?

Tags: loops, react-native, nested-loops

i have json and i want to nested loop in react native. how can i nested while SECTIONS in Accordion?

```
const SECTIONS = [
    {
        title: 'Monday',
        content: {
           '1':'washing dish'
           '2':'work'
        },
    },
    {
        title: 'Tuesday',
        content: 'Lorem ipsum...',
    },
    {
        title: 'Saturday',
        content: 'Lorem ipsum...',
    },
];

_renderContent = section => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.contentCon}>
                <Text>{section.content}</Text>
            </View>
        );
    };

<Accordion
                        activeSections={this.state.activeSections}
                        sections={SECTIONS}
                        renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
                        renderContent={this._renderContent}
                        onChange={this._updateSections}
                    />
```

how to loop render content to get washing dish and work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate through an object using `Object.keys` or `Object.values`:

```
renderContent = (section) => {
  const { content } = section;

  if (typeof content === 'string') {
    return (
      <View style={styles.contentCon}>
          <Text>{section.content}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.contentCon}>
      {Object.keys(content).map(key => (
        <Text key={key}>
          {content[key]}
        </Text>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}
```